# UITableView issue in appium

Tags: ios, uitableview, appium, appium-ios

I'm testing an scenario to verify the cell values for `UITableView` in appium. Appium provides the correct values for the visible cells, but incorrect values for the invisible cell.

For eg.,  A table is having 30 rows, 20 is visible and 10 is not visible. The table returned to the tests has the top 20 ones correct. The last 10 has the same information as the 30th row.

Do we have any work around for this issue?

Comment: Try to scroll into the hidden tow while testing !

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Objective C, but it's my understanding that these tableView cells are created as needed.  If they aren't visible on the screen, there's a good chance that they haven't been created, or may have been deleted and would not have an accurate value. I hope this insight is helpful.